# update global dictionary in multiple File

Tags: python

I need to update global dictionary which use in multiple file and tried multiple
option but it did not work.

```
# test1.py

cell = {'A' : a,
        'B' : b}

# In test2.py

from test1.py import cell
cell['C'] = c  # One way
globals().update(cell)  # did not work also

# In test3.py

from test1.py import cell
print cell  # not getting update cell dictionary
```

Comment: `a`, `b`,`c` are string?

Comment: How do you combine the modules? Do you probably try to **store data persistently** in a python module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `test2` is not imported before test3 in the current process then of course `cell` is not modified...

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/impglob$ cat test1.py
cell = { 
    'A' : 1,
    'B' : 2 
    }
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/impglob$ cat test2.py
from test1 import cell
cell["C"] = 3
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/impglob$ cat test3.py
from test1 import cell
print cell
import test2
print cell
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/impglob$ python test3.py
{'A': 1, 'B': 2}
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2}
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/impglob$
```

**BUT** module-level globals (mutable globals that is) are already bad and are better avoided whenever possible. *Shared* globals - code in one module updating a global in another module - are pure evil. IOW : **don't** do this. There are ways to structure your code so you don't need such a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Modules are `singleton` in python. So they are imported only once. So when you update an mutable object in any module, it would automatically be reflected in others. It could only happen if you have printed in `test3.py` before `test2.py` is executed.

Comment: Seems you are describing why the actual observation of the asker cannot happen?